# How can I extend SilverStripe "system/internal" routing?

Tags: routes, silverstripe

I have some tree pages like:

```
/business
/loans
/personal
/bad-credit
etc.
```

How can extend internal/framework routes (without creating child pages) to get links like:

```
/business/segment
/loans/some-segment
/personal/some-another-segment
/bad-credit/awesome-segment
etc.
```

Something like this:

```
---
Name: customroutes
After: framework/routes#coreroutes
---
Director:
  rules:
    'business/???': 'Custom_Controller'
    'loans/???': 'Custom_Controller'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need custom routing - you just need to add an allowed_actions to your page controller as described here: http://doc.silverstripe.com/framework/en/tutorials/2-extending-a-basic-site#creating-a-rss-feed

The example shows rendering an rss feed, but this can be adapted to rendering a normal page.

Here's a simplified example:

```
<?php

class MyPage extends Page {

}


class MyPage_Controller extends Page_Controller {

    private static $allowed_actions = array(
        "segment",
    );


    // URL: domain.com/page-url/segment
    public function segment() {

        // By default this will look for the template MyPage_segment.ss
        // If that's not found, it will fall back to MyPage.ss
        // Then Page.ss and so on...
        return $this->render();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! But what about dynamic allowed actions?

Comment: This page should help with that: http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/topics/controller