# Get content of paginated pages via ajax, filter it and append it to current page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, silverstripe

I would like to load more functionality on my blog. I now have paginated pages, which is not what I want. I thought it would be easy to get the contents of these paginated pages via ajax, filter it, and append it to a div.

I'm not really sure if this is the way to go. This is what I tried:

```
$("a.next").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var nextLink = $(this).attr("href");
    console.log(nextLink);

    $.ajax ({
      url: "http://localhost:8888/" + nextLink,
      datatype: 'html',
      type: "GET",
      success: function(data) {
        var response = data;
        $(".blogItems .holder").append(response);

      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
        alert(err.Message);
      }
    });
  });
```

Can you guys point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you using a blog module? If so, which one? Also, what is the value of nextLink? IF you haven't already, you'll need an ajax endpoint which renders only the part of the template you need.

Comment: yes i am using the blog module. the silverstripe blog module. NextLink has the value of the pagination that comes with the silverstripe module and poins to the next page. I don't really understand what you mean with an endpoint? can you explain it?

Comment: By endpoint I mean the URL you're requesting. This could be an action on a controller for example. I'd advise adding an extension to the blog holder controller which handles the ajax request. You can learn more about actions here: http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/topics/controller Here's another recent example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24570107/how-can-i-extend-silverstripe-system-internal-routing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution would work, providing that you'd detect the ajax call in the back end, and instead of the entire page, return just the parts where you are interested in (use Director::is_ajax() for that, and follow the hints in the comment of @micmania). If you would rather not make your controllers more complex and you don't mind the extra data being sent, you could also just retrieve the entire page (as you are doing now), and pick just the parts that you want to append to your existing document:

```
$.ajax ({
  url: "http://localhost:8888/" + nextLink,
  datatype: 'html',
  type: "GET",
  success: function(data) {
    var response= $("#theDivIWant", data); //<- Here (untested, but should do the trick
    $(".blogItems .holder").append(response);
  },
  error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
    alert(err.Message);
  }
});
```

This solution also degrades nicely for people not using javascript, although I'm not exactlye sure if that's of any added value these days :-)

Comment: This is a solution, i tested the code above and it worked. I will try to implement the other suggested method as well